# HTML / CSS Set everything on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is this: when inserting a new button in navbar the User Name goes to the bottom line. My goal is for everything to be aligned on the same line.

I have already used `display: inline-block` and `flex-direction: row` but it did not work. Can someone help me?

[image: Image Problem]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-10 p0">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="min_navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Home ")">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Tabelas ")">Tabelas</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Registo ")">Registo</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Quem Somos</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu other_dropdwn">
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about-2.html">About Us-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu other_dropdwn">
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services-2.html">Services-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Notícias</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "News ")">Últimas Notícias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" SingleNews ", "News ")">Notícia Singular</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Contact ", "Home ")">Contactos</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Login ", "Account ")">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav_searchFrom"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-avatar-flat-icons/512/User_Avatar-44-512.png" class="rounded circle" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" /> Nome</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Perfil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog-2.html">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS as well

Comment: Is this bootstrap? And if so, post which version you are using

Comment: You need to use `display: flex` on the `nav` element. `inline-block` acts as inline elements, which means, once the element has no more room it will go to the next line.

Comment: Yes, I'm using bootstrap

Comment: If you use bootstrap probably your navbar is too big for container element.

Comment: Replace col-md-10 to col-md-12 to use the full width of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navbar may be too big, so it won't work. But, if it is not too big, this might work:

Here, add a class. I chose `floater`:

```
<li class="dropdown submenu floater">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-avatar-flat-icons/512/User_Avatar-44-512.png" class="rounded circle" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" /> Nome</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="blog.html">Perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-2.html">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In your CSS, do:

```
.floater {
    float: right;
}
```

You may have some extra margin or padding somewhere in your code, so I would check that.

Comment: Fixed the problem, but if you add some more ... then move to the bottom line

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider moving from float to flexbox or grid to set position of elements!* We have "killer-features" in CSS nowadays, like Flexbox or even better CSS Grid (but there's some lacks of browser support). Yep, it's quite difficult to handle it at the begining, but when you'll understand how to roll with it - you'll love it!

> I have already used display: inline-block and flex-direction: row but
>   it did not work. Can someone help me?

You can't combine display: inline-block with flex-direction, because you're trying to combine flex with blocks. You should use *display: inline-flex* instead.

HTML Markup:

```
<ul class="d-flex">
  <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
  <li>Ad, quas.</li>
  <li>Recusandae, minima.</li>
  <li>Tempore, sint.</li>
  <li>Consequuntur, porro.</li>
  <li>Ipsum, at!</li>
</ul>
```

SCSS Markup:

```
.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul {
  li {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

Here you can try with flex: 
https://codepen.io/dstolarski/pen/XOYEwR

Comment: not every browser / device supports flexbox. If a property is still in the W3C specs, it can and should be used if project scope permits. This is one of the hard things about stackoverflow because 99% of the time you don't know what the user requirements are in terms of those devices, so it's best to reserve those for opinion based discussions

Comment: in fact there is a bootstrap inline class called `float-right` so there are some cases where it is needed, not that this is one of them, I'm just saying your answer sounds like you're persuading people NOT to use it **EVER**

Comment: Come on, flexbox is supported even by IE 10 (which I must support in my projects :| ).
Float is more tricky to handle in complex project than the flexbox. And if you are getting the BS point-of-view - all of the columns are based on flexbox in BS4, not on float. 

But. Yes - you're right - CSS can be tricky and sometimes you can use float. But IMHO, now it should be done at last. (I didn't had to use it in my projects when I'm using flexbox)

Comment: Right. My argument isn’t about it’s usefulness @DawidStolarski it’s that you’re essentially telling people *not to use it* when there are numerous scenarios where it can be used, even in 2019 and even in conjunction with flex driven projects. Just because you don’t need it and use flexbox for everything doesn’t mean future readers are.

Comment: Yes, but please consider the topic of this problem. You should use flexbox in this case. The one answer(added before) was with the floating method, - and IMHO, this is the problem - that somebody, who is learning, can read that float is the first proper way - but it isn't, when you can get solved by flex or css grid and everything is moving to this way.

But, I've removed the part with "DON'T USE IT EVER" - to be good with your opinion! :)

Comment: I don't have anything against your solution to the problem, and if I were to answer I would likely answer with flex as well, but 'Proper way' is subjective. `float` applies to **all** elements, flex properties don't. That's a huge reason to be careful how you word things. Because yes, a new learner can come to this question and read your answer and assume it applies to all situations, which is also not proper. Another cool thing about float is that text can wrap around it, while flex boxes, are... well boxes and it doesn't work the same, they are not synonymous. Float is very useful still.

Comment: I meant this particular case, and used words which could be misunderstanding for new learners. Good point! :) Thank you for this conversation, it has massive feedback.